# Why doesn't dirt need luck?

Tags: futurama

Out of all the obscure jokes and references in *Futurama*, this one puzzles me the most: In The Luck of the Fryrish, the professor says that "dirt doesn't need luck" and looks very content. What does he mean by that?

Comment: Are you of the opinion that dirt needs luck?

Comment: The great thing about this TotW is that it remembers me of all these awesome quotes and makes be chuckle every time :)

Comment: I put this quote on our winery's t-shirts. As a Pinot Noir specialist, this quote needs no further explanation. I recall PF saying 'Dirt Doesn't Lie' at some point too

Comment: I watched this scene again, and the only basis I can found for why it's funny (and it IS funny) is that it's referencing the fact that the professor is old, and slightly senile., i.e., he's stating something incredibly obvious and feeling proud that he knows it.

Comment: I agree with others the main point of the joke was the Professor's weird pedantry, but I wonder if someone on the writing staff might have been a fan of the 90s indie band [Helium](https://pitchfork.com/thepitch/1511-what-makes-mary-timony-a-guitar-god-according-to-sleater-kinney-sadie-dupuis-and-more/) whose debut 1995 album was called ["The Dirt of Luck"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dirt_of_Luck)

Answer (score 10):

We shouldn't read *too* much into this joke, but I believe there is an actual "*science* fiction answer" to this line.

Farnsworth is a scientist, and by extension a science buff. A better portion of this group (I'm afraid this includes me) likes to make Spockanian comments, state the obvious, technical corrections or wisecracks (call it what you like). In this instance he's correcting Fry's sentiment that the four-leafed clover is now bringing luck to some lump of dirt (something along those lines). This explains his content look, because he's correcting Fry allegedly thinking dirt would require the features provided by the clover (while this is without doubt obvious, even for Fry).

Comment: This is no doubt possible, but I'm still puzzled by the professor's content look, because he usually reacts to stupid comments with anger. It got me thinking that it was really a reference to something else about dirt in some obscure science fiction material.

Comment: @Jakob: Possibly, but it's quite vague, if it is. At least it doesn't ring a bell with me.

Comment: @Jakob - The content look is probably meant to suggest his self-satisfaction at just having corrected Fry on this "misconception", which is funny because it's such a stupid point to make.

Comment: Is it just me, or did anyone else "hear" this answer in Farnsworth's voice?

Answer (score 0):

Necro on this, but I don't care.  That statement and sentiment is meta for this answer.

I've thought about this one carefully ever since I heard it, because it is such a great line, and I've always been under the impression that it's not self-satisfaction, but a sense of admiration, respect, and possible envy, for dirt.

He emphasises "need" in such a way that indicates dirt is ALREADY fortunate, beyond the scope of anything that luck could possibly provide.

Why he considers it such is pure conjecture, but here we go:

Dirt has many fascinating qualities.  It's omnipresent, studied, ancient, and forever.  Dirt never goes away, and is effectively beyond even an immortal state.  You can't kill dirt, good luck removing it, and have fun trying to ignore it. You cannot escape from dirt.  and eventually?

You will BECOME dirt.

The professor perhaps sees dirt as the final form of all that exists, and considers this a state so beyond our true comprehension, that why would it need an inherent force to garner further favour?

thus, dirt doesn't NEED luck.

Comment: "Dirt is omnipresent... and forever?"  Truly?  There was no dirt at the Big Bang.  There would be no dirt without planets, so any particular patch of dirt can live only as long as the planet it is on.  There will be no dirt after the Big Rip, or the Big Crunch, or whatever end the universe reaches.  There might be something here to hang an answer on, but overreaching weakens your argument.  You might be better off saying "dirt doesn't need luck because nothing worse can happen to it."

Comment: and here we have the reason I avoid Stack :D  There's too much dirt, you can't get away from it, good luck removing it, and have fun trying to ignore it.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but I am trying to push you to firm up and defend your answer.  So I aim to be nice, but a _little_ bit pushy; apologies if it doesn't come off well.  We don't object to speculative answers, but we do want them to be _high quality_ speculative answers.

Comment: This answer is much better than the more upvoted one (though as acknowledged it is 10 years late!). The tone that the professor speaks _clearly_ implies that dirt is already as lucky as it gets, which is why it's so funny (and why I'm laughing now in my office)